# Spring Boot OAuth2 Security properties names in .properties files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm currently learning and experimenting with the different Spring Boot Security OAuth2 packages and I'm really confused with the actual configuration properties names. I found on the internet and on multiple Spring Documentation pages different naming schemes for these properties. For example I found

```
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=xxx
security.oauth2.client.resource.tokenInfoUri
spring.security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=xxx
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver ...
...
```

I'm trying to make sense of all this and would like to know what are the differences with all of them. Are they version related, package related, are they typos, are some names deprecated, ... ?

Regards

P.S. I'm currently using Spring Boot 2.2.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spring Security OAuth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) & [Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security)

> The Spring Security OAuth project is deprecated. The latest OAuth 2.0
> support is provided by Spring Security

The property entries starting with

```
security.oauth2.*
```

are part of the deprecated Spring Security OAuth ( [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html5/#common-application-properties) ) and the properties starting with

```
 spring.security.oauth2.*
```

are part of the Spring Security ( The official documentation of current spring boot [Security Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#security-properties) )

Additional References

- [Spring Security OAuth 2.0 Roadmap Update](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update)
- [OAuth 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide)
- [OAuth 2.0 Features Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix)

Answer (score 3):

There are two OAuth implementations for Spring Security: the deprecated Spring Security OAuth project and the new Spring Security 5 OAuth classes.

These properties are for the deprecated project:

```
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=xxx
security.oauth2.client.resource.tokenInfoUri
```

And these are for Spring Security 5:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=...
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver=...
```

You can find more info in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024206/spring-security-oauth2-vs-spring-security-oauth2-core-in-spring/56024752#56024752).

PS. Using the spring-boot-starter-security starter will import Spring Security 5.